# AMPQ: TypeError: Cannot read property 'deliveryTag' of undefined

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I have a topic exchange and I am testing a user test case which is if error occurred then send false acknowledgement.

```
ch.bindQueue(q.queue, ex, ‘key’);
      ch.consume(q.queue, async (msg) => {
        console.log(" Sub: [x] %s:'%s'", msg.fields.routingKey, msg.content.toString());
        const eventInfo = JSON.parse( msg.content.toString());
        try
        {
          throw ‘error occurred’;
         }catch(err) {
          ch.nack(‘error occurred’);
        }
      }, {noAck: true});
    });
```

It returns the following error:

> (node:550) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'deliveryTag' of undefined

[Referring doc](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_ack).

Can someone suggest what can be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

We should reject the message and not passing a string to the `nack` method:

```
ch.bindQueue(q.queue, ex, ‘key’);
  ch.consume(q.queue, async (msg) => {
    console.log(" Sub: [x] %s:'%s'", msg.fields.routingKey, msg.content.toString());
    const eventInfo = JSON.parse( msg.content.toString());
    try
    {
      throw ‘error occurred’;
     }catch(err) {
      ch.nack(msg); // <----------------
    }
  }, {noAck: false}); // <----------------
});
```

Notice that using `nack` will put the message in the queue again whereas the `ack` not...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry